# How to get a user's activity on a particular page in Twitter?

Tags: api, twitter, request, postman

I am trying to check whether a user has tweeted or @mentioned to a particular page, but could not find any api to achieve this

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=<User ID>
```

- this api will return the page's timeline posts but in my case i need to check if a user has mentioned my page or tweeted about my page

Answer (score 0):

If by "page" you mean a web page, you can search for tweets with the standard search API, with the `q` parameter as `from:@user url:example.com/yourpage`.

You can even try in online :
https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=from%3Aosibot%20url%3Aen.jeffprod.com&src=typd
(this is searching for tweets containing urls to the domain `en.jeffprod.com` posted by the user `@osibot`)

Note that with the API you will get tweets from the last 7 days only.

Reference :
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/standard-operators.html